# After selecting a face , the bevel modifier works automatically , and can not quit it

Tags: modeling

In edit mode, after selecting a face, blender automatically enters Bevel
and can not quit it. So I could not do anything else.
I reinstalled blender 2.81, the problem still happened.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a possibility you might have changed a hotkey?

To be sure you have the factory settings, you can reset to factory preferences, to reset go to edit-> preferences-> click the 3 rows in the bottom left corner -> load factory preferences.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It really works.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really works.  I wonder why reinstalling blender does not restore the default preference. I did wonder if the preference was set by mistake, so I have reinstalled Blender. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, as to why the hotkeys don't reset after a reinstallation, blender saves the config files in a different place, for future reference search: %appdata% in windows -> blender foundation -> blender -> blender version -> config